# Using iptables to only allow masquerade LAN hosts to access static internet IP, is this possible?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

Is there a way to allow intern LAN hosts to masqueraded to a single static internet IP?

I've been playing around with the following script and only blocking the gateway console but my LAN systems still can get out through the gateway system to any address.

```
#iptables -I FORWARD -j DROP all; echo blocked everything!

LAN_IN="eth0"
INTERNET="eth1"

#get IP of FQDN
ip="184.28.161.165"
#ip=`nslookup $1 | grep -m2 Address | tail -n1 | cut -d : -f 2`
#[[ -z "$ip" ]] && { echo "Error: URL not found in $_db"; exit 1; }


# Clean old firewall
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
        
# Unlimited access to loop back
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Drop everything
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

# Allow DNS
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface $INTERNET -j MASQUERADE


echo "Attemptin to open ip $ip"
echo "----------------------------"

# Now, allow connection to website site on port 80, 443, and icmp
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d $ip  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -d $ip  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -d $ip -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT


# unlimited access to LAN
iptables -A INPUT -i $LAN_IN -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o $LAN_IN -j ACCEPT

# Drop everything
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

echo " "
echo " --------- new fw -------------- "
iptables --list-rules
```

My results reflect this in the list

```
Attempting to open just access to www.apple.com( 184.28.161.165)
----------------------------

 --------- new fw --------------
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT DROP
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 184.28.161.165/32 -p tcp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 184.28.161.165/32 -p udp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 184.28.161.165/32 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is a proxy I think. If the other computer can access the gateway  physically (layer 2), you can not block the connection from the proxy. Perhaps vlan help to you?

Comment: The system is a standard linux host running a masquerading nat gateway.  I thought of using a proxy, but due to the site we need to access. It can not be redirected proxy and must be contacted directly.  Also the application does not read system or allow configuration of a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old one but if that is still needed, i'll try to make an answer.

## TL;DR:

you need to restrict the MASQUERADE rule so that it's not applied outside of the allowed contraints.

## A bit more background/detail

You need to understand that depending on the conditions/path of a network packet, all tables/chains are not always triggered.

Routed traffic will go through multiple table+chains but it will not go through the sames as locally generated or targeted trafic.

More specifically, the INPUT/OUTPUT chain of the main table are not in any use when routing externally received packets, they will however go through (not limited to) the PREROUTING/POSTROUTING chains in the tables raw,mangle & nat, and also the FORWARD table.

In your case, if you only want to allow masquerading LAN packets targetting [www.apple.com](http://www.apple.com) you could write your masquerade rule like so:

```
LAN_NETWORK=192.168.0.0/24
TARGET_IP=184.28.161.165
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --source $LAN_NETWORK --destination $TARGET_IP --out-interface $INTERNET -j MASQUERADE
```

You'll more often see a split of the phases "limiting destinations" and mangling/nating, but you could still need to handle trafic in different way depending on the sources (if you have multiple NAT ip for exemple).

```
LAN_NETWORK=192.168.0.0/24
TARGET_IP=184.28.161.165
# allow routing/forwarding this specific trafic:
iptables --append FORWARD --source $LAN_NETWORK --destination $TARGET_IP -j ALLOW
# disable everything else (using a custom LOGDROP chain that would LOG and then DROP)
# you could simply DROP, or even change the default for FORWARD to DROP
iptables --append FORWARD -j LOGDROP
# Then you'd have a more generic NAT rule in POSTROUTING:
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --source $LAN_NETWORK --out-interface $INTERNET -j MASQUERADE
```

## Multiple destinations

If you have multiple addresses / network that need to be allowed then you have multiple solution, the best one would probably be to switch over to a direct nftable syntax, but with iptables you could:

### cram every destination in the same rule:

```
iptables --append FORWARD --source $LAN_NETWORK --destination $TARGET_IP,$TARGET_IP2,$TARGET_NET1 -j ACCEPT
```

### Use multiple rules

```
iptables --append FORWARD --source $LAN_NETWORK --destination $TARGET_IP -j ACCEPT
iptables --append FORWARD --source $LAN_NETWORK --destination $TARGET_IP2 -j ACCEPT
iptables --append FORWARD --source $LAN_NETWORK --destination $TARGET_NET1 -j ACCEPT
```

### or use a custom chain

It could help the readability of the configuration, if the list of destination is used in multiple rules something like:

```
iptables -N IPLIST
iptables --append IPLIST --destination $TARGET_IP -j ACCEPT
iptables --append IPLIST --destination $TARGET_IP2 -j ACCEPT
iptables --append IPLIST --destination $TARGET_NET1 -j ACCEPT

# limit routed (and so masqueraded) trafic:
iptables --append FORWARD --source $LAN_NETWORK -j IPLIST
iptables --append FORWARD -j DROP
# also limit local outbound trafic:
iptables --append OUTPUT -j IPLIST
iptables --append OUTPUT -j DROP
```

There is so much way to do this kind of thing

## Detailed schema

If you want to learn a bit more on the subject [there](https://stuffphilwrites.com/2014/09/iptables-processing-flowchart/) is an excellent diagram showing the different path availables for processing packets in iptables from Phil Hagen:

[image: iptable processing chart]